# Set Heigth of Div at creation time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have  following  css class

```
.QueueHeader {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    height: 91px !important;
    width: 53% !important;
}
```

and i have wriiten following code in javascript :

```
 var divContent = document.getElementById("content");
 var divQueueNumber = document.createElement("div");

 divQueueNumber.className = "QueueHeader";
 divQueueNumber.style.height = '190px';
 divContent.appendChild(divQueueNumber);
```

i want to set height of div Element dynamically at creation time, i have set height in javascript code.. but it doesn't effect..
how can i set it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you appended your newly created div to DOM? document.body.appendChild(divQueueNumber) ?

Comment: In your case, you want to have min-height in your CSS and height in your javascript. You should get into the habit of using jquery whenever you're manipulating DOM. If not, you're going to run into a situation where cross-browser incompatibilities are going to hurt.

Comment: remove !importance from your code, it overrides values which are given at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have added the !importance in your CSS .

CSS rules marked !important take precedence over later rules. Normally in CSS the rules work from top to bottom, so if you assigned a new style to an element further down the style sheet or in a secondary style sheet then the later rule would take precedence. !important ensures that this rule has precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing jQuery, you can do this instead:

```
$('<div>')
    .addClass('QueueHeader')
    .height(190);
```

But still it won't work since the height in your CSS class has `!important` which overrides inline styles, which is used when jQuery applies styles to elements. Remove `!important`.

As far as I know, the order of style importance is like this, with 1 as highest priority:

1. User styles (like link colors in the browser settings)
2. `!important` styles
3. inline styles
4. styles in style tags and link tags (rules of specificity applies)
5. browser defaults